# I can eliminate the Lagrange multipliers "automatically" when $n=2$ or $3$. How do I extend this to higher dimensions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

The motivating problem is the familiar

$$\begin{align}
\text{maximize} \quad
& F(x_1, \cdots,x_n) \\
\text{subject to} \quad
& G_i(x_1, \cdots,x_n) = c_i,\quad i=\{1, \cdots,m\}
\end{align}$$

$F: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is maximized (or minimized) subject to the $m$ constraints $G_i: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R} = c_i$.

For $n=2$ and $n=3$ where there is only $m=1$ constraint, the authors of [this online textbook](http://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/MathML/index.xhtml) have a nice way of performing the method of Lagrange multipliers that "automatically" eliminates the value of the Lagrange multiplier itself. The general idea is to find $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ such that $\nabla F(\vec x)$ and $\nabla G(\vec x)$ are parallel, then apply the constraint $G(x_1,\cdots, x_n) = c$ to these $x_j$.

When $n=2$ and $m=1$, [they assert that the determinant](http://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/MathML/chapter14/example01.xhtml) of the $2\times 2$ matrix whose columns are  $\nabla F$ and $\nabla G$ is zero:

$$\det \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial G}{\partial x_1}\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial G}{\partial x_2}\\
\end{bmatrix} = \det \begin{matrix}\Biggl[
\nabla F(\vec x) & \nabla G(\vec x)\Biggr]\end{matrix} = 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

This determinant and $G(\vec x) = 0$ amount to two equations in two unknowns, and solving for $x_1$ and $x_2$ is straightforward.

When $n=3$ and $m=1$, [they assert that the cross product](http://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/MathML/chapter14/section03.xhtml) is zero:

$$\nabla F(\vec x) \times \nabla G(\vec x) = \vec 0 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

This system lets us eliminate one of the $x_j$, and again we have two equations in two unknowns when we apply $G(\vec x) =0$.

**I would like to generalize this approach to problems with additional constraints and/or in higher dimensions.**

---

For $n=2$ and arbitrary $m$, we can set $m$ determinants equal to zero:

$$\det \begin{matrix}\Biggl[
\nabla F(\vec x) & \nabla G_i(\vec x)\Biggr]\end{matrix} = 0, \quad i=\{1, \cdots,m\} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

For $n=3$ and arbitrary $m$, we can set $m$ cross products equal to zero:

$$\nabla F(\vec x) \times \nabla G_i(\vec x) = \vec 0, \quad i=\{1, \cdots,m\} \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

The challenge comes with larger values of $n$. I notice that matrix in $\eqref{eq1}$ is square whenever $m = n-1$. **Can I use the same "determinant trick" in any such case?** That is, are these conditions sufficient for finding critical points?

$$\det \begin{bmatrix}
\vert&\vert&&\vert\\
\nabla F(\vec x) & \nabla G_1(\vec x)  & \cdots  & \nabla G_{n-1}(\vec x)\\
\vert&\vert&&\vert\\
\end{bmatrix} = 0 \\
\text{and} \\
G_i(x_1, \cdots,x_n) = c_i,\quad c=\{1, \cdots,n-1\} \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

My intuition says **no**, because the matrix on the left will be singular if just one of the $\nabla G_i$ is parallel to $\nabla F$, or if one of the $\nabla G_i$ is a linear combination of the others.

1. **Is my intuition correct,** that the determinant in $\eqref{eq5}$ ensures optimality only for $n=2, m=1$?

I notice that in going from $\eqref{eq1}$ to $\eqref{eq2}$ (and $\eqref{eq3}$ to $\eqref{eq4}$), switching from a determinant to a cross product turns the right hand side from a scalar $0$ to a vector $\vec 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

2. **Is there a generalization of the cross product** that I can use to test whether two vectors $\vec a, \vec b \in R^n$ of any size $n$ are parallel?
3. As in $\eqref{eq1}$ and $\eqref{eq2}$, **is there a way to write the first-order optimality conditions for Lagrange optimization without including** the $\lambda_i$ variables for arbitrary $n$ and $m$?

---

Edit: [Reading further in this section](http://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/MathML/chapter14/section04.xhtml), **the same authors also apply the determinant trick to the** $n=3,m=2$ case. Where $G(\vec x) = H(\vec x) = 0$ are constraints (which, taken together, describe a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$), the condition is

$$\det \begin{matrix}\Biggl[
\nabla F(\vec x) & \nabla G(\vec x) & \nabla H(\vec x)\Biggr]\end{matrix} = 0$$

from which we eliminate one of the three variables and solve for the other two using $G(\vec x) = 0$ and $H(\vec x) = 0$.

I think this rests on the unstated assumption that $\nabla G(\vec x) \times \nabla H(\vec x) \neq \vec 0$. Indeed, if $\nabla G(\vec x) \times \nabla H(\vec x)$ is zero, then either those two surfaces are the same, and the constraints are redundant, or $G(\vec x) $ and $H(\vec x)$ are separated by a constant, and the problem is infeasible.

But **have the authors addressed the possibility** that $\nabla H$ is some other linear combination of $\nabla F$ and $\nabla G$? Then the matrix would be singular for all $\vec x$.